# Oracle Error:12505 TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, netbeans

I tried to connect my Netbeans Java project to Oracle Database but it showed the error `ORA:12505 TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor`.

Even when I used SQL Developer to connect, I received the same error.

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thank you in advance.

NOTE: I use the command `SQLPlus` in `CMD` and it works fine. My listener is not resting.

UPDATE:
Here is my `listener.ora` file context:

> SID_LIST_LISTENER =   (SID_LIST =
> (SID_DESC =
> (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
> (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Oracle)
> (PROGRAM = extproc)
> (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\Oracle\bin\oraclr19.dll")
> )   )
>
> LISTENER =   (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
> (DESCRIPTION =
> (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
> (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
> )   )

and here is the result of `lsnrctl` status

> LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on
> 13-MAY-2021 18:36:25
>
> Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Connecting to
> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
> STATUS of the LISTENER
> ------------------------ Alias                     LISTENER Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production Start Date
> 13-MAY-2021 17:28:29 Uptime                    0 days 1 hr. 7 min. 56
> sec Trace Level               off Security                  ON: Local
> OS Authentication SNMP                      OFF Listener Parameter
> File   C:\Oracle\network\admin\listener.ora Listener Log File
> C:\Oracle\base\diag\tnslsnr\DESKTOP-A10GTQJ\listener\alert\log.xml
> Listening Endpoints Summary...
> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DESKTOP-A10GTQJ)(PORT=1521)))
> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=DESKTOP-A10GTQJ)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=C:\ORACLE\BASE\admin\system\xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
> Services Summary... Service "48f123709e024effbc4514551f7222c6" has 1
> instance(s).   Instance "system", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for
> this service... Service "52448234712340b69f274bcc790ecfe0" has 1
> instance(s).   Instance "system", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for
> this service... Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).   Instance
> "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
> Service "orclpdb" has 1 instance(s).   Instance "system", status
> READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service... Service "system" has 1
> instance(s).   Instance "system", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for
> this service... Service "systemXDB" has 1 instance(s).   Instance
> "system", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service... The
> command completed successfully

Comment: You will need to post an example of the connect strings involved, the content of your listener.ora file, and the output of `lsnrctl status`.

Comment: Thanks, I uptated the question,.

Comment: It is better to add the actual text to your question, rather than links to images.

Comment: As a side observation, it appears that you have named your container database 'SYSTEM'.   Not a very good choice.  First, names really should convey some meaning, and SYSTEM doesn't really do that.  Second, SYSTEM is also the name of one of the default accounts within the database and while there is no techinical conflict, it will make discussion and communication rather error prone.  When naming the container, why not just go with the default of CDB?

Answer (score 0):

CLRExtProc is *not* the SID of the database. It is an extension that allows Oracle to communicate with external .Net libraries. If you are trying to connect to the pluggable database I see listed, then you *must* use service_name, not SID, for that database. Your connection string would then look like this:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin@//localhost:1521/orclpdb
```

Note: In a container / pluggable database architecture, SID only ever points to the *container* database, which should never be used to hold application objects. In general it is better to use service_name whenever possible.

See here for additional JDBC connection string formats: https://www.oracle.com/a/tech/docs/java-programming-with-oracle-database-19c.pdf

Comment: Thank you, I tried reinstall Oracle and did exactly what you said and it worked perfectly, but I had to change "localhost" in the URL to my ID address.

Answer (score 0):

Btw, you can enable [USE_SID_AS_SERVICE_listener_name](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/netrf/oracle-net-listener-parameters-in-listener-ora.html).
In this case you can connect to your service even if you specifying your service name in SID.

Comment: This would still only allow connection to the container database, not the PDB.

Comment: @pmdba just interesting why do you think so? Did you read its description? "Database clients with earlier releases of Oracle Database that have hard-coded connect descriptors can use this parameter to connect to a container or pluggable database."

Comment: @pmdba example: https://gist.github.com/xtender/282c8ab39e44024073dc013d22b8d050

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at it backwards. You're right.